# Keep the menu open when child or grandchild is active using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot change the HTML as it is generated.

Like the title says, if the grandchild `Terms II` in Terms 2 is active, then `Terms 2 > Terms B` should remained open. Likewise, if the child, `Terms I` in Terms 3 is open, then `Terms 3` must remained open. How can I go about this?

**JSFiddle DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/t2sz3ogv/**

PS: I have created 3 different HTML in JSFiddle to show the different scenarios for your convenience.

PSS: Please note that the parent `Market` is hidden permanently.

HTML:

```
<div class="moduletable">
    <ul class="nav menupolicies">
        <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header hide">Market</span>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                <li class="deeper parent"><a href="/market/terms">Terms 1</a></li>
                <li class="current active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 2</span></span>
                    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                        <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa">Terms A</a></li>
                        <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header "><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png" alt="Fleet"><span class="image-title">Terms B</span></span>
                            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                                <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsb/i">Terms I</a></li>
                                <li class="current active"><a href="/market/terms/termsa/ii">Terms II</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa/iii">Terms III</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 3</span></span>
                    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                        <li class=""><a href="/market/terms3/i">Terms I</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent ul").hide();
jQuery(".menupolicies>li>ul").show();
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent > span").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent .nav-header").click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).find("img").toggleClass( "arrow" );
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.menupolicies>li {
  width: 100%;
}
.menupolicies .parent {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.menupolicies a, .menupolicies li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
.menupolicies .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menupolicies .parent span img {
  width: 24px;
  float: right;
}
.menupolicies .arrow {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that: find each parent of `li.active` and show them:

```
$("li.active").parents('ul.nav, ul.nav-child').show();
```

```js
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent ul").hide();
jQuery(".menupolicies>li>ul").show();
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent > span").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
jQuery(".menupolicies .parent .nav-header").click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).find("img").toggleClass( "arrow" );
});

$("li.active").parents('ul.nav, ul.nav-child').show();
```

```css
.hide {
 display: none;
}
.menupolicies>li {
  width: 100%;
}
.menupolicies .parent {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.menupolicies a, .menupolicies li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
.menupolicies .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav {
 margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menupolicies .parent span img {
  width: 24px;
  float: right;
}
.menupolicies .arrow {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moduletable">
  <ul class="nav menupolicies">
    <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header hide">Market</span>
      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="current active deeper parent"><a href="/market/terms">Terms 1</a></li>
        <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png" class=""><span class="image-title">Terms 2</span></span>
          <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa">Terms A</a></li>
              <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header "><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png" class=""><span class="image-title">Terms B</span></span>
                <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                  <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsb/i">Terms I</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsb/ii">Terms II</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsb/iii">Terms III</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png" class=""><span class="image-title">Terms 3</span></span>
          <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
            <li class=""><a href="/market/terms3/i">Terms I</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="moduletable">
 <ul class="nav menupolicies">
  <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header hide">Market</span>
   <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
    <li class="deeper parent"><a href="/market/terms">Terms 1</a></li>
    <li class="current active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 2</span></span>
     <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
      <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa">Terms A</a></li>
      <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header "><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png" alt="Fleet"><span class="image-title">Terms B</span></span>
       <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsb/i">Terms I</a></li>
        <li class="current active"><a href="/market/terms/termsa/ii">Terms II</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa/iii">Terms III</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 3</span></span>
     <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
      <li class=""><a href="/market/terms3/i">Terms I</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="moduletable">
 <ul class="nav menupolicies">
  <li class="active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header hide">Market</span>
   <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
    <li class="deeper parent"><a href="/market/terms">Terms 1</a></li>
    <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 2</span></span>
     <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
      <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa">Terms A</a></li>
      <li class="deeper parent"><span class="nav-header "><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png" alt="Fleet"><span class="image-title">Terms B</span></span>
       <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsb/i">Terms I</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa/ii">Terms II</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="/market/terms/termsa/iii">Terms III</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="current active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28db52g3/ios-arrow-up.png"><span class="image-title">Terms 3</span></span>
     <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
      <li class="current active"><a href="/market/terms3/i">Terms I</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh you beauty. Thank you so much. I couldn't think of that. So simple! :)